# nsdata dataWithBytes causing crash on iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, char, nsdate

It's crashing on iOS7 only

```
+(PageSection *)initwithPageSection:_anchor withHeader:_subHeader withDetails:_text withPhoneNumberIfValid:(id)_phoneNo
{
    const char *tempAnchor = [_anchor cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
    const char *tempSubHeader = [_subHeader cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
    const char *tempText = [_text cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
    const char *tempPhoneNo = [_phoneNo cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];

    NSData *anchorData = [NSData dataWithBytes:tempAnchor length:[_anchor length]];
    NSData *subHeaderData = [NSData dataWithBytes:tempSubHeader length:[_subHeader length]];
    NSData *textData = [NSData dataWithBytes:tempText length:[_text length]];
    NSData *phoneData = [NSData dataWithBytes:tempPhoneNo length:[(NSString *)_phoneNo length]];



    PageSection *p =[[PageSection alloc]init];
    p.anchorTag=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:anchorData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    p.subHeader=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:subHeaderData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    p.text=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:textData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    p.phoneNo=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:phoneData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return p;
}
```

this line cayusing th crash: `NSData *textData = [NSData dataWithBytes:tempText length:[_text length]];`

Any idea??

Comment: Is there any crash log in your console ?

Comment: no error on console. only EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: What is up with your method signature? Why are there no types for _anchor, _subheader, etc?

Comment: actually it's gining NULL but only for iOS7
const char *tempText = [_text cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
    NSLog(@"tex: %s", tempText);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually it's returning NULL but only for iOS7 `const char *tempText = [_text cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]; NSLog(@"tex: %s", tempText);`

That's why it's crashing

Answer (score 0):

You'r trying to access a released object.

Go to your product>Edit Schemes>Diagonistic Tab> Enable zombie objects. It will tell you which object is being accessed after released memory.

Comment: I gave a try to this but it's not letting me know about that object